# Is there a way to Integrate Firebase Crashlytics with my github repository

Tags: android, github, crashlytics

The idea here is that if there is a major crash on my app, it should generate a github issue with crash log and line number etc on my github repository.

Answer (score 3):

With a quick google I could find [this repository on Github](https://github.com/oddbit/crashlytics-github).

I'm not the owner of the repo but a quick glance shows that they have used Cloud Functions to [create the issues](https://github.com/oddbit/crashlytics-github/blob/develop/functions/src/github-api.ts#L67) sending the Github API calls when they get [a crashlytics issue from Firebase](https://github.com/oddbit/crashlytics-github/blob/develop/functions/src/index.ts#L22) (`firebase-functions.handler.crashlytics.issue.onNew`).

I'd suggest you fork the repo and change it how you like it. This way you can update the dependencies with no worries.

Comment: A great answer! Thanks

Comment: This is js side, how can we implement this on native android side

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you are asking how to implement crashlytics to native Android? Here's a [link to the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android). It's pretty detailed and should help you get the job done. If you're asking how to call cloud functions from the native app, here's a [link to the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).